# How multiple file transfer through parallel connection between single client and server using java socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

Here, the parallel connection between a single client and server.
Suppose, I have 5 files, want to send them simultaneously through parallel connections as similar to the following figure.

[image: Figure that shows parallel connections between Client and Server]

In my code below, I have tried to implement to create 2 connections and try to send 2 files through these 2 connections. But my code is not working as expected.
I want anyone's help to complete my job.

**Server Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private static String dir = "E:\\DestinatioFolder\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket[] servsock = new ServerSocket[5];
        Socket[] sockets = new Socket[5];


        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            servsock[i] = new ServerSocket(5050+i);
            sockets[i] = servsock[i].accept();
            System.out.println("New Connection....");
        }
        int i=0;
        while(i<2) {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sockets[i].getInputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            Thread t = new ClientHandler(sockets[i++], bis, dis);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

class ClientHandler extends Thread {
    final String dir = "E:\\DestinationFolder\\";  // you may change this
    final BufferedInputStream bis;
    final DataInputStream dis;
    final Socket socket;
    public ClientHandler(Socket socket, BufferedInputStream bis, DataInputStream dis ) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.bis = bis;
        this.dis = dis;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
                try{
                    long fileLength = dis.readLong();
                    String fileName = dis.readUTF();

                    System.out.println("FILE Name: "+fileName);

                    File file = new File(dir + fileName);

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    for (int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) {
                        int b = bis.read();
                        bos.write(b);
                    }
                    bos.close();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Server: "+e);
                } finally {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Connect closed.");
                    if(dis != null) dis.close();
                    if(socket != null) socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Client {
    private static String dir = "E:\\SourceFolder\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Socket[] sock = new Socket[5];
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            sock[i] = new Socket("localhost",5050+i);
        }
        File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles();
        sendFile(files,sock);
    }

    private static void sendFile(File[] files, Socket[] sock) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    sock[i].getOutputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
            Thread t = new ClientThread(files[i], bos, dos);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

class ClientThread extends Thread {
    final BufferedOutputStream bos;
    final DataOutputStream dos;
    final File file;

    public ClientThread(File file, BufferedOutputStream bos, DataOutputStream dos) {
        this.dos = dos;
        this.bos = bos;
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            long length = file.length();
            dos.writeLong(length);
            String fileName = file.getName();
            System.out.println("FILE: "+fileName);
            dos.writeUTF(fileName);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

          
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                int b = bis.read();
                bos.write(b);
            }
            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat confused. Do you *really* want to *reduce* throughput? In any case there is only one network. Using multiple connections through it won't materially affect throughput one way or the other unless the files being transmitted are very small.

Comment: I also see no advantages in your approach, but, coming back to the question, you have a multithreaded server and a single-thread single-socket client, so you open just one connection in your code.

Comment: 'Multiple parallel connection with a single connection' is a contradiction in terms. Unless he is asking you to implement a superimposed multiplexing protocol? I suggest you post the actual wording of the assignment, in your question. Not what you think it means.

Comment: Regarding 'Separate Connection' my implementation is correct or need to modify?

Comment: It's working but i am confused if my implemention is based on separate connection or not that's why asking. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't have any code that creates multiple connections in the client, do you?

Comment: I was searching in google found so some code for multi-client connect based on those i implemented this code. That means i developed it for multi-client. But i am little bit confuesed about separate connection. Separate connection and multi-client connection i don't know these are same meaning, is it?

Comment: I don't have a code that creates multi-connection with a single client.

Comment: I agree. You don't. So write it. Your question?

Comment: @user207421 I have modified the question and added a figure to make question explicit

Comment: I don't think that you understand how a java ServerSocket works. Have you ever implemented a client/server system that works with a single connection?

Comment: Yes, i have implemented for single connect. Actually, i am very new with socket programming.

Comment: You don't need multiple `ServerSockets`. Just multiple `accept()` and corresponding `ClientHandler` threads. You need to read the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Okay.Do i need to modify in Client Class?

Comment: Are you asking again whether your own code works?